# Effect of `nosplash` in /boot/cmdline.txt

Tags: boot, plymouth

I am trying to understand the effect of `nosplash` in the kernel commandline parameters. This is currently undocumented, but I'm basically obtaining a different behavior depending if its presence or not. For comparison, this is what I see:

- `splash` : the regular splash screen is seen, at boot/poweroff;
- `nosplash` : only the 4 raspberries are seen, no console messages at boot, *completely blank screen* at poweroff;
- (nothing) : the 4 raspberries are seen along with messages, at boot/poweroff;
- (other words that end with "splash") : does the same thing than the (nothing) case above.

The last test may seem strange, but this was to verify if plymouth only checked the "splash" suffix from the kernel commandline, somehow, which seems not to be the case.

I really don't understand this difference in behavior...

Version of plymouth: 0.9.2-4
/etc/issue: `Raspbian GNU/Linux 9`